# intersection of (group of groups)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

if 
$X=\{ 1, \ 2 \}$ , and $R=(P(x), \Delta , \cap )$

$A=\{ \phi , \ \{1\} \}$ , prove that $(A, \Delta , \cap )$ is ideal in Ring $R$.

I know how can I prove that, but I only have qusetion in intersction

know, if I want to find $A \cap \{1\}$,

is it like this

$A \cap \{1\} = (\{\{1\}, \phi \}) \cap \{1\}= \{1\}$

or like this

$A \cap \{1\} = (\{\{1\}, \phi \}) \cap \{1\}$

$\{1\} \cap \{1\} = \{1\} $

$\{1\} \cap \phi = \phi$

so $A \cap \{1\}=\{\phi, \{1\}\}=A$

what's the true answer ?

Comment: $A\cup\{1\}=\big\{\varnothing,\{1\}\big\}\cup\{1\}=\big\{\varnothing,1,\{1\}\big\}$; $A\cup\{\{1\}\}=A$, however, since $\{1\}\in A$ already.

Comment: The second thing is what you should do, although note that both of your computations are incorrect.  In your first computation, the union of the set $A$ with the set $\{1\}$ is $$\{\emptyset, \{1\}, 1 \}$$ and not $\{1\}$, as Brian mentioned.  In your second computation, note that $\{1\} \cup \emptyset$ is $$\{1\}$$ not $\emptyset$.

Comment: I am so sorry, I mean intersection not union :(

Comment: I've retagged - "intersection theory" refers to a particular branch of algebraic geometry, not the general study of intersections of sets.